# Obtener imagen en escala de grises para detectar contornos con opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Tengo este codigo para detectar contorno, marcalos y contarlos, pero me aparece este error en el momento de intentar pasar la imagen a escal de grises como corrijo esto?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

camino= "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg"
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg")

grises= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2GRAY)

bordes= cv2.Canny(grises, 100, 200)

_, ctns, = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
print('Numero de contornos es ', len(ctns))
texto= 'Contornos encontrados ' + str(len(ctns))

cv2.putText(img, texto, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,  
    (255, 0, 0), 1)


cv2.imshow('Bordes', bordes)
cv2.imshow('Imagen', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

este es el error:

```
grises= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2GRAY) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp:1678: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == 1 && dcn == 1 in function 'cv::demosaicing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizandolo de la siguiente forma:

```
grises = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: jaja, desaparecio ese error pero ahora me sale este otro:

Comment: cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar la imagen en escala de grises lo puedes hacer desde la función imread, pasando cómo segundo parámetro 0.

```
img = cv2.imread("my_image.jpg",0)
```

Respecto a tu error de findContours es debido a que utilizas openCV 4.1.1. En versiones anteriores la función regresa 3 valores. En OpenCV>4.0 regresa únicamente 2. Por lo que deberías utilizar:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Más información en la documentación de OpenCV.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html